# From a single string to 1 column DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

why this (1):

```
lst = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'b', 'd'] 
df = pd.DataFrame(lst) 
df
```

gives this output:

```
    0
0   a
1   b
2   c
3   d
4   a
5   b
6   d
```

but this (2)

```
chars = 'A A A A A A A A A A B B B B B C C C C C C C C C D D D D D D D E E E E E F F F G G G G G H H H H'
df = pd.DataFrame([chars.split()])
df
```

gives this output:

```
0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39  40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47
0   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   B   B   B   B   B   C   C   C   C   C   C   C   C   C   D   D   D   D   D   D   D   E   E   E   E   E   F   F   F   G   G   G   G   G   H   H   H   H
```

How can I have **only one column** in the (2) output please?

Comment: Don't wrap `charts.split()` in a list, it already returns one.

Answer (score 1):

This will give you the desired output:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(chars.split())
```